# how to Find nearest line for the given point from a collection of lines?

Tags: postgis, pgrouting

I have table with lines(linestring).For a point wich i give it , I want to find out nearest line in point.
I almost developed a query, but it is return the same line every point i give.

the query

```
   SELECT "NAME_LABEL", ST_Distance(ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(40.587840 22.951521)',4326),2100),geom) AS distance FROM geom ORDER BY distance ASC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: What is your table called that contains the column geom. Do you want to find the nearest point on each line to the given point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query looks fine to me - are you certain of your point coordinates? The geometry produced by "ST_GeomFromText('POINT(40.587840 22.951521)',4326)" is in Saudi Arabia. Is this what you expect?

Comment: TThank you the coordinates is 22.9151521 40.587840 is the correct i put it upside down

Comment: For not open a new threed i have a problem with this query to express in php '$sqlSta ="SELECT *,ST_Distance(ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POINT("$lgnSta"' '"$latSta")',4326),2100),geom) AS distance FROM roads ORDER BY distance ASC LIMIT 1;";'  But is not work